# Having trouble with adding nodes to an AVL tree in C

Tags: c, binary-tree, avl-tree

For my assignment I am tasked to create an AVL tree and print out the values in a breadth-first fashion, my professor wants us to create a tree with 10,000 entries, which is a different problem for later, my issue is the fact that the `Struct AVLnode * AVLnodeAdd(struct AVLnode * current, TYPE newValue)` is causing problems because of its recursive nature. I have tried multiple times  to approach this from a different perspective and each time it causes in a segfault. I think my "end" statement is just inherently wrong. I just want to loop through each tree in order to find an empty node.

my avl.c file

```
/* add newValue to subtree of current node */
struct AVLnode * AVLnodeAdd(struct  AVLnode * current, TYPE newValue)
{
    if ((current == 0)) {
        struct AVLnode *newNode = (struct AVLnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct AVLnode));
        newNode->val = newValue;
        setHeight(newNode);
        return newNode;
    }
    else {
        current->left = AVLnodeAdd(current->left, newValue);
        current->right = AVLnodeAdd(current->right, newValue);
    }
    return _balance(current);
}
```

avl.h file

```
struct AVLnode {
    TYPE         val;
    struct AVLnode *left;
    struct AVLnode *right;
    int height;
};


struct AVLTree {
    struct AVLnode *root;
    int          cnt;
};
```

I have tried to make the if statement equal to the `current->val = 0` I have tried to check both the left and right nodes like `(current->left == NULL) && (current-right == NULL)`

Comment: It looks like there is a fundamental absence of understanding about how binary search trees (BST) in general work. (An AVL tree is a kind of BST). Perhaps go back to the lecture nodes or read online material like [this](https://www.codesdope.com/course/data-structures-binary-search-trees/) (not the best presentation out there but it has helpful animations, try to figure out what is going on in them).

Comment: Every time you add a new value to this tree, you're adding two new leaves to _every_ leaf node in the tree. This will be a complete disaster!

Comment: I think that the code you provided is far away enough from a valid solution that it is clear you need to learn a little more about binary and self-balancing trees. I think the link that n.m. listed above is very good, but also check out this GA tech website where you can see the process and some pseudocode as items are added to an AVL tree: [link](https://csvistool.com/AVL)